# Button in each dynamically created linear layout dont work only button in last linear layout work

Tags: android, android-layout, button, android-linearlayout

```
    public class MyStock extends Activity
    {

        DatabaseHelper db;
        DownloadFileviaHTTP1 d;
        private mItems[] itemss;
        EditText txtPriceEdit=null;
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        public ListView lst_stockListing;
        List<HashMap<String, String>> fillMaps ;
        ArrayList<mItems> planetList = new ArrayList<mItems>();
        RelativeLayout slider = null,listview=null,topHeader=null,remaniningBucks=null,r,layoutName=null;
        Button btn_leftpanel,btn_editstock,btnbuy,btncancel,btnaccept,btnsub,btnadd,btnsell,b1,b2;
        String[] from = new String[] {"companyName", "ButtonBuy", "currentPrice", "ButtonSell"};
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.txtstockname_custom, R.id.btnbuy_custom, R.id.txtcurrent_custom, R.id.btnsell_custom };
        TextView txtnifty=null,txtremainingbucks=null,txt_stockqty=null,txt_quantity=null,txtPrice=null,txtPriceChange=null,t1=null,t2=null;
        LinearLayout mainLinear=null,l=null;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.mystock);

            //Button
            r=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainStock);

            btn_leftpanel=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_leftpanel);
            btncancel=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btncancel);
            btnaccept=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnaccept);
            btnsub=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_sub);
            btnadd=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
            btn_editstock=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_editstock);

            //layout
            listview=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.listview);
            slider = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_relative_slider);
            topHeader=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_top_header);
            layoutName=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_name);
            remaniningBucks=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_remainingbucks);

            //TextView
            txtnifty=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtnifty50_text);
            txtremainingbucks=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtremainingbucks_text);
            txt_stockqty=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtstockqty);
            txt_quantity=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtquantity);
            txtPriceEdit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtprice_edit);
            txtPrice=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtprice);
            txtPriceChange=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtprice_change);

            //listview
            lst_stockListing=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lst_mystock);

            itemss = (mItems[]) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();

            d=new DownloadFileviaHTTP1();

            txtnifty.setText("100000.00");
            txtremainingbucks.setText("100000.00");
            txtremainingbucks.setTextColor(android.graphics.Color.rgb(105,160,38));

            ArrayList<Items>details = new ArrayList<Items>();

             mainLinear=new LinearLayout(this);
             mainLinear.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
             mainLinear.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

             DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(MyStock.this,"StockApp");
             db.getReadableDatabase();
             Cursor cur=db.view_mystock("TBL_MYSTOCK", db);
             Log.d("cursor count : "," " +cur.getCount());

             Items item;
             int i=0;
             int j=52;
             Log.d("curcount : ",""+cur.getCount());
             while(cur.moveToNext())
             {
                    l=new LinearLayout(this);
                    l.setId(i);
                    l.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.common_grid2);
                    l.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,70));

                    t1=new TextView(this);
                    t1.setWidth(210);
                    t1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    t1.setHeight(55);

                    btnbuy=new Button(this);
                    btnbuy.setId(i);
                    btnbuy.setHeight(55);
                    btnbuy.setWidth(75);
                    btnbuy.setTextColor(Color.rgb(105, 160, 38));
                    btnbuy.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buy_stock);

                    t2=new TextView(this);
                    t2.setWidth(112);
                    t2.setHeight(55);

                    btnsell=new Button(this);
                    btnsell.setId(j);
                    btnsell.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sell_stock2);
                    btnsell.setWidth(75);
                    btnsell.setHeight(55);
                    Log.d("valu of i and j","" +i +" " + j);

                    l.addView(t1);
                    l.addView(btnbuy);
                    l.addView(t2);
                    l.addView(btnsell);
                    mainLinear.addView(l);              
                    i++;
                    j++;
                    t1.setText(cur.getString(1));
                    t2.setText(cur.getString(2));

                 if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(6).toString())>0)
                 {
                    btnbuy.setText(cur.getString(6));
                    btnbuy.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buy_stock_number);
                 }

                // details.add(item);
             } 
             listview.addView(mainLinear);

            function();
        }

       void function()
        {
            btn_leftpanel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {   
                    Intent in =new Intent(MyStock.this,ListingItem.class);
                    startActivity(in);
                }
            });

            btn_editstock.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {   
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {   

                    Log.d("top position ","" +listview.getTop());
                }
            });
            btncancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    Log.d("cancel","called");
                    slider.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });
            btnaccept.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {   
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {               

                }
            });
            btnadd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    int val=Integer.parseInt(txt_stockqty.getText().toString());
                    if (val<100)
                        val=val+10;

                    txt_stockqty.setText(""+val);
                    txt_quantity.setText(""+val);
                    txtPriceEdit.setText(""+txtPrice.getText().toString());
                    float val1=Float.parseFloat(txtPriceEdit.getText().toString());             
                    txtPriceChange.setText("" + val*val1);
                }
            });
            btnsub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {   
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    int val=Integer.parseInt(txt_stockqty.getText().toString());
                    if (val>10)
                        val=val-10;

                    txt_stockqty.setText(""+val);
                    txt_quantity.setText(""+val);
                    txtPriceEdit.setText(txtPrice.getText().toString());
                    float val1=Float.parseFloat(txtPriceEdit.getText().toString());
                    txtPriceChange. setText(""+val*val1);
                }
            });
            txtPriceEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
            {
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {

                }
            });
            btnbuy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    Log.d("button id : ",""+btnbuy.getId());
                        slider.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                         DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(MyStock.this,"StockApp");
                            db.getReadableDatabase();
                            Cursor cur=db.view_mystock("TBL_MYSTOCK", db);
                            Log.d("cursor count : "," " +cur.getCount());
                            db.close();
                            cur.move(btnbuy.getId());
                            while(cur.moveToNext())
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(MyStock.this,cur.getString(2), 1000).show();
                                txtPrice.setText(cur.getString(2));
                                txtPriceEdit.setText(cur.getString(2));
                                Float i=Float.parseFloat(txtPrice.getText().toString()) * Integer.parseInt(txt_quantity.getText().toString());
                                txtPriceChange.setText(""+i);
                                break;
                            }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

At run time I'm creating linearlayout. The no of linear layouts that are created are the  no of records in the database .The linear layout is having two textbox and two buttons. The problem I'm facing is that only the button of the last linear layout work. The buttons of the previous linear layout is not working.

Comment: Try to use ArrayAdapter or BaseAdapter it will helps you..

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below code..

```
public class CustAdp extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    Cursor cursor_subCat;

    public CustAdp(Context context, Cursor cursor_subcategory) {
        super(context, id);
        this.cursor_subCat = cursor_subcategory;
        cursor_subCat.moveToFirst();
    }

    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return cursor_subCat.getCount();
    }

    public String getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        cursor_subCat.moveToPosition(position);
        return cursor_subCat.getString(cursor_subCat
                .getColumnIndex("Sub_CatName"));
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        cursor_subCat.moveToPosition(position);
        return cursor_subCat.getInt(cursor_subCat
                .getColumnIndex("Sub_IdAuto"));
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.notifyDataSetChanged();
        cursor_subCat.requery();
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.customsubcat,
                null);
        ImageView iv_subcat = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.image_region1);
        TextView tv_subcat = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.txt_regionname1);
        Button btn_subcat = (Button) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.button_delete_subcat);

        cursor_subCat.moveToPosition(position);
        try {
            byte[] subimage = cursor_subCat.getBlob(cursor_subCat
                    .getColumnIndex("Sub_CatImage"));
            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(subimage, 0,
                    subimage.length);
            iv_subcat.setImageBitmap(bm);
            tv_subcat.setText(cursor_subCat.getString(cursor_subCat
                    .getColumnIndex("Sub_CatName")));
            subcat_id = cursor_subCat.getLong(cursor_subCat
                    .getColumnIndex("Sub_IdAuto"));
            btn_subcat.setId((int) subcat_id);
            id = cursor_subCat.getInt(cursor_subCat
                    .getColumnIndex("Sub_MyReceipe"));
            convertView.setId(position);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }



        btn_subcat.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                temp = v.getId();
                Cursor c_subcat = db_SubCategory
                        .getReceipeFromSubCategory(temp);
                c_subcat.moveToFirst();

                if (c_subcat.getCount() == 0) {
                    data = false;
                    showDialog(0);
                } else {
                    data = true;
                    showDialog(0);
                }

            }
        });
        return convertView;

    }

    class ViewHolder {
        TextView tv_subcat;
        Button btn_subcat;
        ImageView iv_subcat;
    }
}
```

Make changes in above code as your requirement...Hope it will help you..

Comment: Meghs i cant able to get what u r trying to see. plz help me....thanks in advance

Comment: Hi..Add your button click event into while loop not in the function().It works fine for me.You can add button's click event after if condition in your code..Just try it..@Chag Vaibhav P

Comment: Welcome..If answer is true then accept the answer..so it will help to other users...

Answer (score 0):

Because my friend, you are setting the "onclicklistener"s to the views selected by the "findViewById" (before the while loop), and therefore only setting the listener to one set of view.
What you want to do it put the content of the "function()" inside the loop, and change the view names of that function to the view name that are inside the while loop.

ex.

```
while(cur.moveToNext()){
    btnbuy=new Button(this);
    btnbuy.setId(i);
    btnbuy.setHeight(55);
    btnbuy.setWidth(75);
    btnbuy.setTextColor(Color.rgb(105, 160, 38));
    btnbuy.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buy_stock);
    btnbuy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("button id : ",""+btnbuy.getId());
        }
    });
    ...
}
```

Comment: Also note, don't hardcode column indicies ex. 'btnbuy.setText(cur.getString(6));' use something like 'btnbuy.setText(cur.getString(c.getColumnIndex(YourTableClass.Your_Column_Name_String));'

Comment: DaRk.FoRcE i cant able to get it what u r trying to see because i cant  put the loop of the button creation inside the functin as i m creating the button at the time of creation of the linear layout

Comment: All I am saying is create the `onClickListener` for each `new Button(this);` that you create. Ie. put it in the main loop. 

What you did, was calling the `function()` AFTER the entire creation of ALL the buttons, therefore, ONLY the last pointer got the `setOnClickListener()` added to it. Your issue is not an Android related one, it is more one the logic of your code.

If what I said is still not clear, let me know and I will try to show a quick code.

Btw. 'Meghs' has the idealist solution, but it is more on the complicated side. By that, I mean the next step of what your coding level.

Comment: what u r trying to see that i have i done but on click event of every button i m getting the id of the last button